# Many spark worker exit when read data from Cassandra 3.7

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra

My Spark running on Java1.7, but my cassandra running on java 1.8. When Spark read data from Cassandra, at the beginning a lot of works exit with the following error message:

```
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00007f338d000000, 21474836480, 0) failed; error='Cannot allocate memory' (errno=12)
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 21474836480 bytes for committing reserved memory.
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/jvm-18047/hs_error.log
```

But remaining workers were still running well, finally the job can be finished well. So I'm wondering that should I use the same JDK version for both of them, but they communicate by socket, it should not the JDK version problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks much more like you are just causing the Spark Executor JVM to overload. It's trying to get 21 GB but the OS says there isn't that much RAM left. You could always try reducing the allowed heap for executors?